# Notification on disconnecting Dial-Up connection

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, winapi

I created a Dial-up connection using `RASDIAL.exe` programatically and when the user manually disconnects that connection I want to be get notified.

How to achieve this programatically? Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: Did you ever get any code started for this?

Comment: @Joshua Drake You need to use RegisterDeviceNotification Api to get this.